# Looking for books (or info) on the Thought Process of great scientists

Tags: resource-recommendations, thought-experiment

I have always wondered how great scientists made their discoveries, but none of my textbooks describe their thought process.

I wonder if anyone knows books that explains the **Phenomenon** and **spark** that led any scientists their hypothesis. What specifically inspired them to think so?

Comment: When you're breaking new ground in science, there probably isn't a good description of the thought process involved, as much of the discovery process is trial and error until you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Not in all cases. Albert Einstein was a theoretician who made amazing advances and noone at the same time as his had the same ideas.

Comment: You might find stuff about this in the books by Thomas Kuhn.

Comment: I understand your concerns @DavidWhite, but I really do believe there must be some creative insights (of course there are trial and errors) great minds peaked that led to discoveries.

Comment: @JunSeo-He he is indeed very creative, but imaginations do need inspirations no?

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks! I believe you mean _The Structure of Scientific Revolutions_, I'l definitely check it out!

Comment: This question (v4) seems to be _too broad/off-topic/opinion-based._

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think this question is _off-topic/opinion-based_ (unless you consider there are no books like that). It may be low-key considered broad in _resource-recommendations_, but I think it is quite clear.

Comment: @JunSeo-He, Einstein's notebooks clearly show quite a bit of trial and error when he was searching for the answers to his hypotheses.  100 years or more after his work was published, we usually see only the "sanitized" version of his work, implying that he took a direct path to his answers.